# Port forwarding from docker-compose XXX:443

Tags: python, nginx, docker-compose

I own a python + uwsgi + nginx app.
I am able to launch this app through this docker-compose file:
    version: '3.4'

```
services:    
   backend:
      restart: always
      image: backend:0.1
      depends_on:
       - db
      expose:
       - 5001
      volumes:
       - share_vol_lab:/home/ubuntu/data

   frontend:
      restart: always
      image: frontend:1.1
      depends_on:
       - backend
      ports:
       - 443:443

   db:
      restart: always
      image: postgres:1.1
      environment:
      expose:
       - 5432
      volumes:
       - data_lab:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
   data_lab: {}
   share_vol_lab: {}
```

Everything is working as accepted, which mean i can access to the app at the url:

> https://*host-ip*/login

I would like to run my app a few more times on the same host to act as different environments.
I copied my docker-compose file to different folder changed frontend port from 443:443 to 444:443 to prevent port clashing, in the browser :

> https://*host-ip*:444/login

and the first page (the static html) is indeed successfully loaded.
When i try to login, the request should be reversed proxy to the backend service from nginx, but no response at all.
here is the nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen  80;
  charset utf-8;
  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host/login; 
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  charset utf-8;
  location ~ ^/(scripts.*js|styles|images) {
    gzip_static on;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  location /api/v1 {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass backend:5001;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 60s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 60s;
    uwsgi_connect_timeout 60s;
  }
}
```

and my uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = app.api:app
processes = 5
master = true
socket = :5001
protocol = uwsgi
lazy-apps = true
harakiri = 30
```

Would like to get any help from you guys, thanks!

Comment: I believe that you should also change the ports of the other containers deployed by the docker compose...

Comment: why? nginx should froward the relevant requests to backend:5001 which then backend is translated to the right internal ip